# jQuery Mobile- change the style of basic drop down select menu

Tags: list, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu, select-menu

I have to change the style of the following dropdown select menu:

```
<form>
<div class="ui-field-contain">
    <label for="select-native-1">Basic:</label>
    <select name="select-native-1" id="select-native-1">
        <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
        <option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
        <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
        <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
    </select>
</div>
</form>
```

all the option should display as  list under the label (like Accordion list)

Comment: Are you stuck somewhere?

Comment: I managed to do it, but I stuck with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589349/jquery-mobile-how-to-replace-the-content-of-the-lists-header-to-the-selected